# Adding open in app store links from an iPhone web page

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I was wondering how these type of links are done when a user is on an apple product (iPhone) and I want a open in Apple app store links to appear. The 2 links and the open confirmation box are from the yelp page on my iPhone.

[Screencap of what I want](https://www.screencast.com/t/sf90nkWQi)

Answer (score 0):

You put custom URL scheme codes, like: **itms-apps://** for the App store, and if you want your own App, you register an URL in your App in "**URL types**" info plist key. If it is your own App you might have to check the **shouldStartLoadWithRequest:** method of your webview UIWebViewDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{ 
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"SomeApp"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```